# Parts of statusbar disappearing with IE BHO

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, bho, sendmessage

I have a C# IE BHO in use for an internal company app that is adds a pane to the statusbar with `SB_SETPARTS` (it mitm's the SETPARTS call and inserts an element into the array) and then draws the controls by moving them from a hidden (in-process) form with `SetParent()`

This technique works well but it causes other parts of the statusbar to appear briefly and then disappear. Affected parts seem to be all of the panes that don't have their own hWnd, eg the "Internet | Protected Mode" and icon, and some of those icons that appear in the six panes immediately to the left.

Does anyone know what is causing this? I suspect that either certain messages aren't getting to the statusbar32 control to draw the stuff, or my WindowsForms10 additions are sending out extraneous messages.

Everything appears fine for about a second, and then the other parts just disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the status bar and then showing the status bar.  If this works, it has nothing to do with IE or BHO or WinForms but just Windows.